# Using Microsoft helper API from C++

Tags: c++, header-files, msdn

I would like to use the [help API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from a C++ project. The problem is that I don't see what header I need to include to use it.

I found the Windows.Help.Runtime.dll in system32 but I guess that I need to include some header file where the function prototypes are.

I've been searching for existent C++ code using the Help API but I couldn't find anything.

Thank you.

Comment: Microsoft can not be relied on to support any of their Windows help systems in a next version of Windows. Likewise, they can not be relied on to support the a current VS help system in a new version of VS. They've changed both repeatedly. So it's not a good idea to rely on their technologies. Unless you want to incur a lot of work switching to newest shiniest thingy every second year or so.

Comment: Hi @Cheersandhth.-Alf. I see. Anyway I just need to use the API to do some queries to the help and save some information to a DB so even not being reliable in the future still is good enough if it just works now. What should I import to access the function prototypes? Thanks!

Comment: Well I haven't used this COM based interface, but the docs mention an IDL (Interface Definition Language) file. You can use the MIDL compiler to generate headers from an IDL file. Maybe the `#import` directive can deal with IDL files also, I don't know. For the previous help system there was the Help Workshop which you could install, maybe there's something like that also now.

Comment: I've searched for the IDL file but I can't find it anywhere. :(

Comment: This is advertised as a WinRT component but the .winmd metadata file you'd need to consume it in a C++/CX project isn't included with the SDK.  Rather an odd duck, it isn't the kind of api you'd ever consider using in a WinRT project and it doesn't actually require such a project.  It was written in C#, targets .NET 4.5.  Matches the kind of tooling that MSDN group at Microsoft likes the use, they prefer WPF.  By far the easiest way to use it is from a C# project, you'd need to copy the DLL you found into another directory, then add a reference to it.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant. Thank you but I still would like to use C++ instead of .Net. Even if it is more difficult, how should I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Hmya, users tend to treat SO like a candy store where everything is always possible.  Do kick the tires first with a C# project, the odds that you actually meant to use this api are rather small.  Your question is entirely too unspecific to guess what you want to do with this api.  If that works then [ComVisible(true)] is a trivial way to use it from a C++ program.

Comment: Let's say I just want to open an MSHX file with the API OpenMshx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh768969(v=vs.85).aspx from C++. Simply that.